# combining two different objects in json

Tags: c#, json

Given below is my C# code which is generating some json output:-

```
var collection = new HeaderElements{
    messageid = "hdhd",
    source = "sid",
};

dynamic collectionWrapper = new{
    Header = collection,
    Elements = new{
        timestamp = "lk",
        value = "123"
    }
};

string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Given below are classes used :-

```
public class HeaderElements{
    public string messageid { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}

public class Elements{
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting following output :-

```
"{\"Header\":{\"messageid\":\"hdhd\",\"source\":\"sid\"},\"Elements\":{\"timestamp\":\"lk\",\"value\":\"123\"}}"
```

But I want my output to be in the following format:-

```
"{\"Header\":{\"messageid\":\"hdhd\",\"source\":\"sid\"},\"timestamp\":\"lk\",\"value\":\"123\"}"
```

I am new to json programming and I am not getting any way out to resolve this.

Comment: JSON that you require is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani, I'm sure that the \ are a debugger copy,intead of the real string as the strating and ending ". Remove those and you have Valid JSON (RFC 4627)

Comment: Yes @DragandDrop I removed / but still spaces were left that is why I got error. JSON is correct, my mistake: 

`{"Header":{"messageid":"hdhd","source":"sid"},"timestamp":"lk","value":"123"}`

Comment: And please use class to represent your json object. There is no cost. This way when ever you are in doubt on how to make your class  represent your json you can create use [Tools](http://json2csharp.com/) or Visual Studio Paste special( Paste Json as class). This way you will never fail to format your json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put timestamp and value into an Elements variable. Put them directly into the wrapper like this:

```
dynamic collectionWrapper = new
{
    Header = collection,
    timestamp = "lk",
    value = "123"
};
```

This gives the output you want:

```
{"Header":{"messageid":"hdhd","source":"sid"},"timestamp":"lk","value":"123"}
```